# How to extend an object series in length in python

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, series

I have a series:

```
0    2018-08-02 00:00:00
1    2016-07-20 00:00:00
2    2015-09-14 00:00:00
3    2014-09-11 00:00:00
Name: EUR6m3m, dtype: object
```

I wish to extend the series in length by one and shift it, such that the expected output is: (where today is the obviously todays date in the same format)

```
0    today()
1    2018-08-02 00:00:00
2    2016-07-20 00:00:00
3    2015-09-14 00:00:00
4    2014-09-11 00:00:00
Name: EUR6m3m, dtype: object
```

My current approach is to store the last value in the original series:

```
a = B[B.last_valid_index()]
```

then append:

```
B.append(a)
```

But I get the error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid
```

So I tried:
`B.to_pydatetime()` but with no luck.

Any ideas? I can not append nor extend the list, (ideally im appending) which are objects because they are a list of dates and times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increment your index, add an item by label via [`pd.Series.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.loc.html), and then use `sort_index`.

It's not clear how `last_valid_index` is relevant given the input data you have provided.

```
s = pd.Series(['2018-08-02 00:00:00', '2016-07-20 00:00:00',
               '2015-09-14 00:00:00', '2014-09-11 00:00:00'])
s = pd.to_datetime(s)

s.index += 1
s.loc[0] = pd.to_datetime('today')
s = s.sort_index()
```

**Result**

```
0   2018-09-05
1   2018-08-02
2   2016-07-20
3   2015-09-14
4   2014-09-11
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: You are right, I don't need `last_valid_index`. But, the output I get is:
`
0    1536167985736000000
1    2018-08-02 00:00:00
2    2016-07-20 00:00:00
3    2015-09-14 00:00:00
4    2014-09-11 00:00:00
Name: EUR6m3m, dtype: object`

which I guess, @jpp, is me still fighting with the series I have which is of Type `object`, and, `pd.to_datetime('today')` which is of type `datetime`

Comment: @JunaidMohammad, The first line of my solution has `pd.to_datetime(s)`. I strongly recommend you do the same. With the data you've provided, it clearly works. So you need to be able to either debug this or provide some data where it *doesn't* work. Otherwise all of us are guessing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do appending here:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4])
s1 = pd.Series([5])
s1 = s1.append(s)
s1 = s1.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Simple and elegant output:

```
0 5
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
```